# Let $f(x)=x^{2}$ show that f is differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

The book that I use has no example for proving the function is diffentiable.

It's just give defination of differentiable . 
I don't how exacty prove differentiable at some point.this problem I work by check it has limit and conclude if limit is true and exist it is differentiable

Ok,Let check my proof

we found derivative by using elementary calculus that is 
$f'(x)=2x$ and plug in $0$ in $f'$ [$f'(0)=0$] if it's differentiable $f'(0)=0$ must be true

let $\epsilon >0$

the defination of differentiable is

$$|\frac{f(x)-f(c))}{x-c}-L|<\epsilon $$

in this case

$$|\frac{x^{2}-0}{x-0}-0|<\epsilon $$

$$\frac{(x)(x)}{x}<\epsilon $$

$x< \epsilon$

Choose $\epsilon =\delta $

then $x<\epsilon$

since of f' exist and it's true by definition of limit.

therefore it's differentiable at $0 $

Comment: You can't divide by x-0 that tends to 0.

Comment: @Pieter21 "You can't divide by x-0 that tends to 0" Sorry? Of course they can (and here, they must...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}$$
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x_0+\Delta x)^2-x_0^2}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}(2x_0+\Delta x)=2x_0$$
Then $(x^2)'=2x$

Answer (score 1):

use $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ for $x=0$ we have $$\frac{f(h)}{h}=\frac{h^2}{h}$$ and no calculate the Limit for $h$ tends to Zero.